# Import external static file in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-5, ecmascript-2016

How can I import an external file (`config.js`) from within a webpack bundle?

I have the following file-structure for local dev:

```
/dist/
    /index.html
    /plugin.js
/src/
    /index.ts
/config.js        # This config is only for local dev, will be different in prod
/ ...
```

The `plugin.js` will be moved to and executed by a third-party website.
I want to import the `config.js` (which will in production be provided by the third-party website) inside my `plugin.js`.

I import the `config.js` in `index.ts` like this:

```
import config from "../config.js";
```

I have managed to exclude the `config.js` from `plugin.js` by specifing it in the `externals`-field in the `webpack.config.js` which is working so far:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: [
        "../config.js"    
    ]

}
```

When I open `index.html` however, the `import` statement from `../config.js` is ***not*** getting an error but the `config`-object file is `undefined`.

The file structure of the third-party server in prod looks like this:

```
/ ... /
    /plugins/
        /other-plugin/...  # A bunch of other plugins. Each has its own folder in plugins
        /my-plugin/
            plugin.js      # This is my plugin
        /config.js         # This is the global config file of the server for all plugins
```

***index.ts***:

```
import config from "../config.js";
console.log(config);
```

***config.js***:

```
module.exports = {
   foo: "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `externals` implies that whatever that was exported by `config.js` file would be available at runtime. So for browser, that means, you have probably already injected it via `script` tag or for Node.js, it is already imported via `globalThis` or some equivalent. Your import line - `import config from "../config.js";` is simply gone when the code is bundled. The `external` doesn't mean that it would re-import `config.js` when the code is being run Additionally, the general practice is to use external object configuration instead of array configuration like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  externals: {
    "../config.js": "AppConfig"
  }
};
```

This tells Webpack that whatever was exported by `config.js` file should be available as `AppConfig` object at runtime. Using array syntax is meant for code with side-effects.

Now coming back to possible solution. The recommended option is to use **environment variables** for passing the environment specific values. Assuming your plugin is a library, when it is being consumed and getting bundled as part of application via Webpack, you can make use of [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to inject these values into your code. You can then access those in your code as `process.env.foo`. You should not import `config.js` in your code anywhere.

The second option is to use externals with object configuration as shown above. Change your `config.js` file to UMD or equivalent:

```js
// config.js file

const config = {
   foo: "bar"
};

// Make it available globally
window.AppConfig = config;

// Since `module` is not available in browser.
if (module && module.exports) {
  module.exports = config;
}
```

And finally, import your `config.js` in `index.html` file before your bundled script gets loaded.

```html
<head>
  <script src="/path/to/config.js>"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/bundle.js>"></script>
</head>
```